# What is the difference between allocating a specific sized array vs declaring a specific sized array in function in cpp?

Tags: c++, arrays

Normally a scope of an array in a function ends with it. But if I allocate beforehand then it perfectly returns the array. So what's the difference between allocating array or declaring array?
I am writing the code and the place where I am confused. Is it because of dynamic memory allocation of the first declaration or something else. Can someone elaborate please?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define N 10

using namespace std;

int * get_array() {
    int * p = new int[N];
    //|--- by declaring like this, the array was perfectly returned.

    int p[N];
    //|--- but is case of this declaration the array returned showed garbage value in the main function.
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) p[i] = i;
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int * M = get_array();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cout << M[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are returning a pointer on stack, which may cause runtime crashes.  Never return pointer/reference to local variables (on stack)

Comment: Also, consider compiling with `-Wall -Werror` to help catch these errors.

Comment: @Shaikh Islam  In the second case the returned pointer is invalid because it points to a non-existent object .

Answer (score 0):

In the second case the array is created **in the heap** of the function, so when you exit the function, that array **doesn't exists anymore**.
In the first case, you're reserving memory space to put your array, so isn't local to the function *per se*, and you must handle its destruction

Comment: in the first case, is it heap or stack ?

Comment: @ShaikhIslam If i remember correctly, the **pointer** is in the stack, but the real array you've reserved is simply outside, in the *general use* memory, but it belong to the program which has reserved it.